# Managing normalising a database over time using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

We're just starting to move off of a legacy codebase and begin using .net and Entity Framework Core for most of our new software.

We've migrated our database from our old platform to SQL Server, but the data is old and poorly normalised. We cannot undertake a normalisation project all at once because of the potential impact on the (large) existing codebase in the legacy language, so we are adding primary and foreign key definitions to our database as we go, and regenerating our Entity Framework Core model from scratch as more tables become valid for the framework.

I feel like we're missing some important capabilities of Entity Framework Core by doing this, but I don't really know enough about the framework to identify what it is. I know the generated model lacks completeness (my question was prompted because a table with an Identity column did not have the column marked as `ValueGeneratedOnAdd();` in fact that table does not appear in the `OnModelCreating` method at all) but I don't know whether that's an issue with the database or another mistake I'm making.

My question is: what capabilities are there within Entity Framework Core to manage a rapidly-evolving database model? What should I be doing for myself, and what should I be relying on the `Scaffold-DBContext` command for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EF Core, most of the things you will need will be done by Scaffold-DBContext.  The only things it doesn't handle right now is DBQuery sets.  You will have to manually code those.  Other than that, everything else is handled pretty eloquently by the command.

As far as ValueGeneratedOnAdd(), the only time I have ever seen this as a problem has been Versioned tables.  If you have a versioned table, Scaffold-DBContext will not add that to those fields and you must have those so you will have to manually add those to your code.

Comment: No, they're not Versioned tables. We only have two of those in the database, and they're not in the Model yet. Upon inspection, we're missing ValueGeneratedOnAdd() on about half of the Identity columns in the Model and I just can't see why.

Comment: There's no need for it.  EF Core understands identity columns and doesn't need the annotation that a value is generated on add.  The only reason you need it for versioned is that EF Core doesn't completely implement it yet.

Comment: Oh, I see. The tables where ValueGeneratedOnAdd() is set are actually tables that appear in the Model, but aren't tables I've been looking at directly. They have primary keys that *aren't* the Identity column (those should actually be foreign keys), and that's why the Identity column is being defined as ValueGeneratedOnAdd(). Simple enough to see now you've assured me that it should be working reliably. Thanks.